# Conditional call based on JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I am trying to modify my Javascript page, which uses Ext Js library.(I don't have any idea about ext js, haven't worked on it either)

What I want To do is that based on the JSON DATA particularly the field "successProperty", I want to decide whether to upload the grid or give an alert.

What I can possibly do is to add an event to the class. but i don't Know how to do it.

Can someone give me a nice example which can help me out in achieving what i need .

Thanks.

please let me know if I need to give any more details

thanks again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '[successProperty](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonReader&member=successProperty)' is not what you think. That property is used internally by ExtJS to know how to find out if the method had an error. Its a string containing the "**name**" of the property inside the returned JSON which will tell the ExtJS framework that something went wrong, and not the **error status** itself. So, that is why ExtJS let you "define" that property. And as your server side will be defined by you, you can choose any name you like for your **success status**, and if you choose something different than **`success`** (which is the default `successProperty`) then you define it in the `successProperty` configuration property of the JsonReader.

And the easy way to detect if an error happened when you load a grid is checking the **3rd parameter** (called `success`) of the `callback` in the `load` method:

```
store.load({
    params:{start:0, limit:15},
    callback: function(result, options, success) {
        if (!success) {
            alert('error!!');
        }
    }
});
```

There are more generic ways of handling server side errors, instead of defining a callback on every `store.load` you can use:

```
// Listen to "exception" event fired by all proxies
Ext.data.DataProxy.on('exception', function(proxy, type, action, ex) {
    alert('Error through DataProxy.exception at ' + type + '.'+ action);
});
```

Or if were already using [Ext.Direct](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Direct) you could use its `exception` event (probably you are not using Ext.Direct, so don't expect it just work by itself):

```
Ext.Direct.on('exception', function(ex) { alert(ex.message); });
```

---

I put together a complete example with the first 2 ways of catching errors: http://jsfiddle.net/vZGvM/.
The example has no errors but you can simulate an error by pointing the url of the ScriptTagProxy to any invalid url (it will take a time to respond if you do that, but you will see both alerts).